# Custom serialization/deserialization of objects in PHP (Or Ruby/Perl/Java if easier)

Tags: php, ruby, perl, serialization, deserialization

I would be most appreciative if anyone could provide me with some insight into deserializing and serializing PHP objects based on a not-quite-xml format. I'm not set on PHP either; I'll happily use Perl, Ruby or Java if anyone thinks that would be easier.

The API that I'm working with expects to be called like so (It's not a library system, but this example illustrates the API quite well):

```
 <request>
     <method>getBookInfo</method>
     <elements>
         <type>bookObject</type>
         <string>bookTitle</string>
         <string>2001: A Space Odyssey</string>
     </elements>
 </request>
```

And then provides responses like this:

```
 <response>
     <method>getBookInfo</method>
     <elements>
         <type>bookObject</type>
         <string>bookId</string>
         <string>12345</string>
         <string>bookTitle</string>
         <string>2001: A Space Odyssey</string>
         <string>locations</string>
         <list>
             <length>3</length>
             <string>High St Library</string>
             <string>Queen St Library</string>
             <string>Downtown Library</string>
         </list>
     </elements>
 </response>
```

It would be straightforward if it used a `<key>value</key>` format, but the `<string>key</string>` followed by `<string>value</string>` format has got me puzzled.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

--

Edit - Sample PHP class if needed to help to illustrate a solution

```
class Book {
        var $bookId;
        var $bookTitle;
        var $locations = array('location1', 'location 2');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite an answer possibly, but too long for a comment.

In what way you could go here depends on what exactly you try to achieve. By that i mean mostly how general your algorithm needs to be. If it always is

```
<type>someType</type>
```

and then any number of either

```
<string>key1</string>
<string>val1</string>
```

or

```
<string>key1</string>
<list>
    <length>3</length>
    <string>High St Library</string>
    <string>Queen St Library</string>
    <string>Downtown Library</string>
</list>
```

ended with either another line with `<type>` or one with `</elements>` you could just write some basic script that iterates through the lines until you find `/<type>.*</`, capture that `.*` (in Perl it would be `/<type>(.*)</`) and then looks for the first key in the next line, the first value in the next (if there is `<list>` in the next line, handle accordingly) and so on.
However, that assumes a lot about the format, we know so little about. For example, may there be `<` or `>` in the types, keys or values? If so, the regex become more complicated.
But there might be all other kinds of different kinds of values or keys with no values at all. So if you need something more general, you will need to learn more about the format, preferably some sort of documentation.

Comment: If you want to use `.*`, it needs to be `.*?` to make it non-greedy, or else it will grab everything from the _first_ opening `<type>` to the _last_ closing tag as a single match. Another alternative would be `[^<]*`, which cleanly avoids greediness issues because it doesn't match `<` characters.

Comment: @DaveSherohman Okay, yes, i did assume that each line had only one pair of tags and that types, keys and values contain no `<`. I did mean to match every line individually, that is what i meant by iterate through the lines.